# Trouble with Tor Vadalia in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Today I installed Tor from Ubuntu Software but I do not know how to make it works. Anybody can help me let it works? Please!

Comment: Don't use the Tor in the software center - it's usually out of date and the Tor network will complain.  use the Tor Browser Bundle from below.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Tor Browser from [Tor Browser Bundle](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/tor-browser-bundle-ubuntu-ppa.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

After that, open your Tor Browser via Dash with `tor` or via terminal with

```
tor-browser-en.sh
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]